# How to register a custom modelbinder in MVC4 RC WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I recently updated from MVC4 beta to the RC and have encountered a small issue with a WebApi project. One of the first things I noticed is that the ServiceResolver was removed. Before it was removed I was using it to register a custom model binder provider in the following way:

```
IEnumerable<object> modelBinderProviderServices = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver.GetServices(typeof(ModelBinderProvider));
List<Object> services = new List<object>(modelBinderProviderServices) { new CustomDynamicObjectModelBinderProvider() };
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver.SetServices(typeof(ModelBinderProvider), services.ToArray());
```

The action which took advantage of this model binder provider has the following signature:

```
[HttpPut]
public void Put(CustomDynamicObject model)
```

I tried to replace the old code with the following but with no results:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(typeof(ModelBinderProvider), new CustomDynamicObjectModelBinderProvider());
```

When I tried to PUT data to the given action, the model provider's GetBinder method is not called and the model paramter is set to null. I was able to make the action use the wanted modelbinder using the ModelBinder attribute by changing the signature of the Acion/method to the following

```
[HttpPut]
public void Put([ModelBinder(typeof(CustomDynamicObjectModelBinderProvider))] CustomDynamicObject model)
```

While this works I really wouldn't like to have to use this syntax in all my controllers/actions.

I think I should mention that my model binder provider is inheriting from:

```
System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinderProvider
```

I am saying this because I saw that there is another ModelBinderProvider class in the following namespace:

```
Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ModelBinding
```

To recap: How to register a custom modelbinder in MVC4 RC WebApi ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The model binding rules in Web API have changed since the Beta. The new rules are described in [Mike Stall's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx). Model binding for complex types now only works if you explicitly add a `ModelBinder` attribute to the parameter.

The parameter binding mechanism has changed *again* since the Release Candidate, so you probably want to wait for RTM before making too many changes. There are a couple of other options that might work in the RC version - depending on what the source is of the data you are trying to bind (query string or request body).

- If the source of your data is the request body then you can create a custom `MediaTypeFormatter` rather than a model binder:
- If your data comes from the querystring and you want to avoid explicitly including a `[ModelBinder]` attribute on your parameters, then you may be able to use a combination of a [custom `TypeConverter`](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TypeConvertersTheresNotEnoughTypeDescripterGetConverterInTheWorld.aspx)  and a [custom `IValueProvider`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/23/how-to-create-a-custom-value-provider-in-webapi.aspx).

In the RTM version (or current nightlies), you will be able to use a custom [`HttpParameterBinding`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/05/11/webapi-parameter-binding-under-the-hood.aspx) if the other options don't work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The post you linked to also helped me get things straight.